# Any Alternative to Rinetd Port-to-IP Forwarding?

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, forwarding

I need to redirect port 443 to external IP. Rinetd works well but it has a bug where it generates huge log files to the point which cripples your server. See bug report here http://markmail.org/message/qo4w4x2grv4aib75

Is there an alternative to Rinetd which forwards all port traffic to external IPs?

Comment: Product recommendations, including alternatives recon, is off topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of tcp proxy servers that will accomplish the same thing.

`xinetd` can forward connections via the `redirect` directive.  See the `xinetd.conf(5)` man page for more information.

[balance](http://www.inlab.de/balance.html) is a simple tcp proxy solution that works well for this sort of thing.

[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) and [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) can both function as tcp proxies.

If you're dealing explicitly with HTTPS connections, any SSL capable web proxy will also get you what you want.  This includes [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and [pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/).

Answer (score 0):

Also check out pen, balance, and crossroads.